# Update MainWindow for dialog

Tags: c++, qt, oop

I have a `MainWindow` with a menu that opens a dialog for registration. How can I update the tableView in the `MainWindow` after the registration?

Here is my `MainWindow` implementation:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);
}


void MainWindow::list()
{
    qDebug() << "test";
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();
    //model->clear();
    model->setQuery("SELECT test_qt FROM db_qt WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)='"+dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")+"'");
    model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("qt_test"));
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}

void MainWindow::on_actionMenu_triggered()
{
    dialog_test->show();
}
```

Here is my Dialog implementation

```
Dialog_test::Dialog_test(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog_test)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void Dialog_test::insert_date(){
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO db_qt(test_qt) VALUES (?)");
    qry.addBindValue(id);
    if (qry.lastInsertId()>0){
        QMessageBox::information(this,"test", "Success");
        MainWindow *mw = new MainWindow(this);
        mw->list(); // I call back list, but not update the tableView the MainWindow.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line in your code

```
MainWindow *mw = new MainWindow(this);
```

creates a **new** main window and updates the list of it. I assume this actually happens, but the window is never shown so you do not see any of it. What you actually want to do is update the list of your **existing** main window.

There are basically two ways of doing that. You can either obtain a pointer to the existing main window (which can be provided to the constructor of the dialog or a method of its own) or use the [Signals and Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) concept of Qt which is the way to go in my opinion.

1. First of all, you define the signal in the header of the dialog:

   ```
   ...
   signals:
       void user_registered();
   ...
   ```
2. Then you emit the signal in your function

   ```
   //MainWindow *mw = new MainWindow(this);
   //mw->list();
   emit this->user_registered();
   ```
3. Make sure the `list()` method is declared as a `SLOT` in the MainWindow header
4. Connect the signal in the MainWindow constructor to call the `list()` slot:

   ```
   ...
   QObject::connect(this->dialog_test, SIGNAL(user_registered()), this, SLOT(list()));
   ...
   ```

With this approach, the dialog does not need to know the main window at all. It basically just tells anyone who is interested that a user registered and the main window acts on it completly by itself.